# get values from XML which is a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get values from an XML string which is like this

```
<ROOT>
<ADDALTERNATE>
<DATA>
<SELECTEDDATA ID="3534" NAME="sampleName" CODE="SampleCode" CODEIDS="133277,133278,133279,133280"/>
</DATA>
</ADDALTERNATE>
</ROOT>
```

How do I get the values from CODE tag from the given XML in javascript simplest way?
tried different way it did not work .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Use `new `[`DOMParser`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)`().parseFromString(` _your string here_ `, "text/xml").`[`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)`("SELECTEDDATA");` to get an [`Element`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) combined with a little [XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) to locate the required value.

```js
const xmlStr = `<ROOT>
<ADDALTERNATE>
<DATA>
<SELECTEDDATA ID="3534" NAME="sampleName" CODE="SampleCode" CODEIDS="133277,133278,133279,133280"/>
</DATA>
</ADDALTERNATE>
</ROOT>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "application/xml");

const code = doc.evaluate(`//SELECTEDDATA/@CODE`, doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
console.log(code.stringValue);
```